# SpineMiss graph shows fractions instead of integers as labels

Tags: r, na

I'm trying to check if the missing values in income vector are somehow related to the job one has. For this I am using VIM library and spineMiss command:

```
library("VIM")
spineMiss(jobmiss910, col = c("skyblue"), only.miss = TRUE, labels = TRUE, cex.lab=0.7,       cex.main=0.8, main = "2010: Fraction of Missing Values per ISCO 1988 Major Job Groups", xlab = "ISCO 1988 job category", ylab = "Frequency")
```

The above yields the result as in the pic.

However, the classification is as follows:
The ISCO-08 divides jobs into 10 major groups:
1-Managers
2-Professionals
3-Technicians and associate professionals
4-Clerical support workers
5-Service and sales workers
6-Skilled agricultural, forestry and fishery workers
7-Craft and related trades workers
8-Plant and machine operators, and assemblers
9-Elementary occupations
0-Armed forces occupations

hence, any fractions should not show up.

Any idea what the cause might be?

[image]

Comment: perhaps your first column in `jobmiss910` have to be `integer` (and is now `numeric`) . I think that is the reason the example `data(sleep, package = "VIM");
spineMiss(sleep[, c("Exp", "Sleep")])` works _correct_ .

Comment: @ckluss it was an ordinal scale, so converting it into integer did not help. Only converting the income into integers did the trick (though it should not happen, as the income might be EUR 2000.2 and it should not influence the categories from the first column..). Now I am wondering how come I should know which missing values are being displayed in VIM graphs (from the first or second column, or maybe both?). In this very case it does not matter, as I have no NAs in the first column. Would you be so kind to post your comment as an answer, so that I can close the question?